# a little help for creating a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a site that admin can add the products that have (title, category , description , and multiple images) ,  and can add category , and categories will be shown in the site and if the visitor clicks on each category, sees the products with that category,and if clicks on each product, sees the description and a slide show for images.
Im completely new in wordpress, I want to know usually such plugins are available on the internet for download , or I have to  make it by my self, please give me help,thanks.

Comment: please help me instead of down votes, i said im new

Comment: There are lots of resources on [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org) please have a look into that also

Answer (score 4):

Hey here is Ready made plugin For that
Ready-ecommerce plugin

http://wordpress.org/plugins/ready-ecommerce/

just remove all Other unnecessary Pages From That.
and let me know if you required Help.

Answer (score 1):

[woo commerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) is the best option to achieve that you want. Do some research on it.

Here are some helpful links:
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/getting-started-with-woocommerce-initial-setup/
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/getting-started-with-woocommerce-launching-your-store/